# How to convert characters in an NSString into elements of an NSSet?

Tags: ios, nsstring, character, nodes, nsset

I have a string such as "abbaaxaa" and I want the characters in the string to be converted into a set such that its elements are "a", "b", and "x"? (I'm a noob coder and I just thought of this implementation to represent the keys for a dictionary, if context matters at all).

I also have code on what I've attempted so far, but it has errors (i.e. where initializing the set and syntax of expressions are concerned) and I am not sure how to go about implementing it... I just know I'm working inside a class (+) method that returns an NSSet.

Comment: Use an `NSMutableSet`. Loop through the strings character by character, implement the loop body to read something like `[set addObject:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 1)]]`

Comment: @H2CO3 this is what I call a pro answer, you cut the road of any other answer with above couple of line ;)

Comment: @Tarek Added it as an answer, I see it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSMutableSet`. Loop through the string character by character, implement the loop body to read something like

```
[set addObject:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 1)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm supposed to return an NSSet, so is there a way to convert NSMutableSet to NSSet? Also, I'm not sure where my mistake is. It's saying "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2" where under the "i" and the "1"... Here's the code I was working with:
{
// class stuff method defining NSString variablesInSet
    NSMutableSet* variableSet;
    for (int i = 1; i < variablesInSet.length + 1; i++) {
        //[variableSet addObject:[[variablesInSet characterAtIndex:i]]];
        [variableSet addObject:[variablesInSet substringWithRange:i,1]];
    }
    return variableSet;
}

Comment: @user2669453 ***facepalm*** 1. You seem to be assuming magic where you would need `NSMakeRange` (apparently you didn't bothered reading my answer fully). 2. read about polymorphism. `NSMutableSet` inherits from `NSSet`. 3. The top of the iceberg: you have an off-by-one error, you should loop from `0` to `length`, not from `1` to `length + 1`... Unsalvageable, hopeless... you are not yet prepared for iOS development, learn some C first. (And **please** try to solve trivial compiler errors yourself, use google and think about problems.)

Comment: I don't know how to say this perfectly solved my sub-problem within my greater code lol... This is my first comment thread.. Well, thanks -- yeah, misread; I was assuming magic lol!

Comment: @user2669453 Blehh, at least it's working now, you're welcome.